# Tiling a Rectangle with integer length horizontal/vertical strips

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers, contest-math

Source: Bay Area Math Circle 1999 (I think)

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. Suppose that a given rectangle can be
tiled by a combination of horizontal $1\times m$ strips and vertical $n\times 1$ strips. Prove that it can be tiled using only one of the two types.

I'm wondering if there is a solution that does not use complex numbers. For reference, the solution is by labeling each unit square of the rectangle with $\zeta^{x}\eta^{y},$ where $(x,y)$ is the square found by moving $(x-1)$ squares to the right and $(y-1)$ squares up from the bottom left corner. The point is that the sum over any horizontal or vertical strip is zero, so the total sum is zero, which is the product of just summing over $\zeta^{x}$ and summing $\eta^{y}.$

Comment: But for that i think m and n should have common multiple except 1

Comment: This seems related and the proofs might be able to be adapted to this particular scenario.  [Fourteen proofs of a result about tiling a rectangle](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Wagon601-617.pdf).  In it, they present several proofs of the theorem "Whenever a rectangle is tiled by rectangles each of which has at least one integer side, then the tiled rectangle has at least one integer side."  If nothing else, when reading the question this result popped into the forefront of my mind.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar - no, it holds in any case.

Comment: @JMoravitz - Yes, I've seen this result before and the article you linked, but I'm not sure how it would help. Thanks, though